# Best way to convert floating point array to integer. [Replacing my asm code for x64]

Tags: c++, visual-c++, assembly, floating-point, 64-bit

I have a function to convert floating point array to unsigned char array. This uses asm code to do that. The code was written many years ago. Now I am trying to build the solution in x64 bit. I understand that _asm is not supported on X64.

What is the best way to remove asm dependency?

Will the latest MS VC compiler optimize if I write C code? Does anyone know if there is anything in the boost or intrinsic funtions to accomplish this?

Thanks
--Hari

I solved by the following code and this is faster than asm

```
inline static void floatTOuchar(float * pInbuf, unsigned char *  pOutbuf, long len)
{
    std::copy(pInbuf, pInbuf + len, pOutbuf);
    return ;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried any code? Do you have sample input and corresponding output?

Comment: Why don't you start with `static_cast<>` (or just implicit conversion) and see if it's fast enough for your purposes...?

Answer (score 1):

With SSE2, you can use intrinsics to pack from `float` down to `unsigned char`, with saturation to unsigned the 0..255 range.

Convert four vectors of floats to vectors of ints, with `CVTPS2DQ` (`_mm_cvtps_epi32`) to round to nearest, or convert with truncation (`_mm_cvttps_epi32`) if you want the default C `floor` behaviour.

Then pack those vectors together, first to two vectors of signed 16bit int with two `PACKSSDW` (`_mm_packs_epi32`), then to one vector of unsigned 8bit int with `PACKUSWB` (`_mm_packus_epi16`).  Note that PACKUSWB takes signed input, so using SSE4.1 `PACKUSDW` as the first step just makes things more difficult (extra masking step).  `int16_t` can represent all possible values of `uint8_t`, so there's no problem.

Store the resulting vector of `uint8_t` and repeat for the next four vectors of floats.

---

Without manual vectorization, [normal compiler output is good](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:g530,options:'-O3+++-Wall+-Wextra+-fno-verbose-asm+-ffast-math',source:'%23include+%3Cmath.h%3E%0A%0Aint+ftoi_truncate(float+f)+%7B+return+f%3B+%7D%0A%0A//+TODO:+how+to+write+this+to+compile+to+cvtsd2si+directly+without+-ffast-math%3F%0Aint+dtoi(double+d)+%7B%0A++return+nearbyint(d)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+ftoi(float+f)+%7B%0A++return+nearbyintf(f)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%0Aint+dtoi_rint(double+d)+%7B%0A++return+rint(d)%3B%0A%7D')),filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,intel:!t,labels:!t),version:3) for code like.

```
int ftoi_truncate(float f) { return f; }
    cvttss2si       eax, xmm0
    ret

int dtoi(double d) { return nearbyint(d); }
    cvtsd2si        eax, xmm0   # only with -ffast-math, though.  Without, you get a function call :(
    ret
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following and let me know:

```
inline int float2int( double d )
{
   union Cast
   {
      double d;
      long l;
    };
   volatile Cast c;
   c.d = d + 6755399441055744.0;
   return c.l;
}

// Same thing but it's not always optimizer safe
inline int float2int( double d )
{
   d += 6755399441055744.0;
   return reinterpret_cast<int&>(d);
}

for(int i = 0; i < HUGE_NUMBER; i++)
     int_array[i] = float2int(float_array[i]);
```

So the trick is the double parameters. In the current code , the function rounds the float to the nearest whole number.If you want truncation , use 6755399441055743.5 (0.5 less).

***Very informative article available at: http://stereopsis.com/sree/fpu2006.html***

Comment: nice article. Thanks

Comment: You'll get faster / better code from letting the compiler use the normal SSE2 float->int conversion instructions.  Use `int foo = nearbyint(d);` to get nearest instead of truncation.  (This [compiles to a single instruction with `-ffast-math`](https://godbolt.org/g/uH4n4f), but I'm not sure how to get ideal code without `-ffast-math`)